# iReport not accepting SQL SUM function

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports, ireport

iReport does not seem to accept the normal SQL SUM function and I am having a hard time figuring out a way around this.

I am trying to use `SUM(qtytofulfill.SOITEM - qtyfulfilled.SOITEM) AS qty` and it does not seem to like that or me simply adding the variables and saying `SUM(qtytofulfill - qtyfulfilled) AS qty`.

This does not seem to be a syntax error but iReport simply will not accept it as an SQL statement. I am posting a picture of me attempting to use this SQL statement and the error it also gives. Any help on what I am doing or even what I actually should be using , specifically, for iReport is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

-Colt

[image]

Comment: have you figured it out?

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode no i have not and i've tried all i know. I do not want every item in the SELECT statement to be SUM(PARAMETER) AS NAME :/ I just want SUM(qtytofulfill.SOITEM - qtyfulfilled.SOITEM) AS qty to be the only thing "summed". And I can't figure out how to do this. I saw another example where someone placed the one SUM function into it's own SELECT statement inside the main SELECT but i can not figure out how to make that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine,

> In standard SQL (but not MySQL), when you use GROUP BY, you must list
>   all the result columns that are not aggregates in the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT
         SOITEM.'QTYFULFILLED' AS QTYFULFILLED,
         SOITEM.`QTYTOFULFILL` AS QTYTOFULFILL,
         SOITEM.`SOID` AS SOITEM_SOID,
         SUM(SOITEM.`QTYFULFILLED`) AS Sum_Quantity_Fullfilled,
         SUM(SOITEM.`QTYTOFULFILL`) AS Sum_Quantity_to_Fullfill,
         (SUM(SOITEM.`QTYFULFILLED`) - SUM(SOITEM.`QTYTOFULFILL`)) AS QTY,
         SO.`ID` AS SO_ID
         FROM
         `SO` SO INNER JOIN `SOITEM` SOITEM ON SO.`ID` = SOITEM.`SOID`
         GROUP BY SOITEM.'QTYFULFILLED',SOITEM.`QTYTOFULFILL`,SOITEM.`SOID`,SO.`ID`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Question i did this and i get the error "Invalid expression in teh select list (not contained in either an ggregate funtion or the GROUP BY clause". I dont have a GROUP BY clause and im unsure as to what to place in it

Comment: Just place `GROUP BY 1` and see if the error is going  ?

Comment: can you paste the query here?

Comment: This actually worked now! Thank you! Can you explain why for me please? I appreciate your patience!

Comment: What DB you are using?

Comment: I am using iReport and using their query designer

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's treating the 2 column names inside sum as variables, not table columns

Comment: That's the issue I am trying to fix. I do not want every item in the SELECT statement to be SUM(PARAMETER) AS NAME :/ I just want SUM(qtytofulfill.SOITEM - qtyfulfilled.SOITEM) AS qty to be the only thing "summed". And I can't figure out how to do this. I saw another example where someone placed the one SUM function into it's own SELECT statement inside the main SELECT but i can not figure out how to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to:

1) check your SQL syntax since you're not grouping on all the non-aggregate columns (you're grouping just on SO_ID)

2) eventualy check the arguments of your sum: alias instead of fields

Comment: That's the issue I am trying to fix. I do not want every item in the SELECT statement to be SUM(PARAMETER) AS NAME :/ I just want SUM(qtytofulfill.SOITEM - qtyfulfilled.SOITEM) AS qty to be the only thing "summed". And I can't figure out how to do this. I saw another example where someone placed the one SUM function into it's own SELECT statement inside the main SELECT but i can not figure out how to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this **jasper report** and it seems that you like both the value of the single record and the sum of all records in your report I would suggest this.

Select your records **without** any sum values.

```
SELECT
 SOITEM.'QTYFULFILLED' AS QTYFULFILLED,
 SOITEM.`QTYTOFULFILL` AS QTYTOFULFILL,
 SOITEM.`SOID` AS SOITEM_SOID,
 SO.`ID` AS SO_ID
FROM
 `SO` SO INNER JOIN `SOITEM` SOITEM ON SO.`ID` = SOITEM.`SOID`
```

Define the fields. es

```
 <field name="QTYFULFILLED" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="QTYTOFULFILL" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Define the sum variables

```
<variable name="SUM_QTYFULFILLED" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QTYFULFILLED}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="SUM_QTYTOFULFILL" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QTYTOFULFILL}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

And thats it!, if you like to output the difference your **QTA** to an textfield

```
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement x="10" y="4" width="100" height="20" uuid="7aa31c20-bd5f-4222-9744-4206d096bb90"/>
    <textElement>
    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format($V{SUM_QTYFULFILLED}.doubleValue()-$V{SUM_QTYTOFULFILL}.doubleValue())]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

*remember to set evaluation time to report (since it needs to finish calculate the variables before printing it)*